# Why is localhost:2000 working, but not any directory behind it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js and was following the code given in this tutorial given at the time 11:33 in order to get the code below. Can someone explain why the error is occurring and how to fix it?

Currently, when I try to access localhost:2000 it works. However, attempting to access http://localhost:2000/client/img/bob.img resulted in this error.

```
Cannot GET /client/img/bob.img
```

Current directory formatting is also specified by the video at 2:35

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfSwUOBL1YQ

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var serv = require("http").Server(app);

app.get('/',function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client/index.html")


app.use("/client", express.static(__dirname + "/client/index.html"));

serv.listen(2000);
```

Comment: Does this happen for every route or just Bob's image?

Comment: Every route that isn't default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please fix the code like below. You specified wrong directory.

```
app.use("/client", express.static(__dirname + "/client"));
```

Comment: I'm blind. That worked. Thanks. Can you explain what else "use" does? Can I "use" more than just /client?

Comment: `app.use()` is binding given middleware to your application. `express.static` is just a built-in middleware to serve static files in express.js. Yes, you can bind `express.static` middleware into multiple routing paths.